# Mapping Inheritance with XStream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

When marshaling classes with inheritance only the child most class data is persisted.

For example, with the code:

```
public class Test {

    static class Person {
        String name;
    }

    static class Employee extends Person {
        String job;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee me = new Employee();
        me.name = "Sam";
        me.job = "Developer";
        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        xStream.alias("employee", Employee.class);
        String xml = xStream.toXML(me);
        System.out.println(xml);
    }
}
```

My output looks like:

```
<employee>
  <job>Developer</job>
</employee>
```

How can I get XStream to output the parent class data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to switch to a newer XStream version. I ran your code with `1.2.2` and get this result:

```
<employee>
  <job>Developer</job>
  <name>Sam</name>
</employee>
```

Comment: This was a bit confusing. The version I'm using is 1.4.4 which didn't work. I tried rolling back to 1.2.2 and it worked as you said. I put in the latest 1.4 version I could find (1.4.8) and it worked.